# How to emit a signal from a combo Box

Tags: c++, qt

I have a slot where I create a combo box and add items, however I want emit a signal to UI manager whenever the user selects an item. I'm wondering if there's a way to use the keyword emit?

I cannot use connect here because, I cannot create an object for the UI manager. 
Not sure I'm making sense or I'm getting my issue across.

```
void Test::dropDown(){
    comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
    comboBox->addItem("Test 1");
    comboBox->addItem("Test 2");
    comboBox->addItem("Test 3");
    comboBox->showPopup();
    //connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::activated), )

    //I want to emit the activated item using the keyword "emit" and not connect
    emit

}
```

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: where is the UI manager class, and what is the relation between it and Test class? is the Test class child of UI manager?

Comment: "I cannot use connect here because, I cannot create an object for the UI manager." - Can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a signal chain connecting two signals instead of a signal and a slot, no reason to *emit* the signal yourself.

Give your `Test` class a signal like this:

```
signals:
    void comboBoxActivated(int index);
```

When you create the combo box:

```
comboBox = new QComboBox(this);    
connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::activated), this, &Test::comboBoxActivated);
```

Now give your UI manager class a slot to receive the `activated` signal:

```
private slots:
    void testComboBoxActivated(int index);
```

Now, if you have an instance of `Test` in UI manager class, like

```
    Test * test = new Test();
```

connect its signal to the manager slot:

```
    connect(test, &Test::comboBoxActivated, this, &UIManager::testComboBoxActivated);
```

This way, the combo will emit the signal in the first place, which will be *forwarded* by the `Test` class and finally received by the UI manager slot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you need to `emit` a signal when a `QComboBox` item is clicked; to do this you need to connect the activated signal to the emit, maybe using a lambda function:

```
connect(comboBox, &QComboBox::activated, this, [this](int index)
{
    // Here emit your signal for the item at index `index`
});
```